# Error to to navigate the database location

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

i made a small program to insert ,update and delete data from access database and it's work fine on computer , but when i copy it to another computer i had problem to to navigate the database location. this is the path in the source code.

```
string DBPath = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Almarkaz.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123456;";
```

Even if i copy the database to the same directory that i have in the source still have problem.
Any ideas please. THANKS ALOT

Comment: Are you sure you have `E:\Almarkaz.accdb` database in that location on other computer? Are you sure you have the right providers? What error or exception you get when you try to connect this database? Describe your problem with more details.

Comment: Did you check that the OLEDB provider exists on the target machine?

Comment: Did you check that the OLEDB provider exists on the target machine?

how to do this?

Comment: _"problem to to navigate the database location"_ is not an error. Please research and share the exact exception message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by the file extension .accdb is the access file, Please make sure you have Microsoft Office Access installed in both the machine and check the file path "E:\Almarkaz.accdb" in both the machine with full access.

good luck.

Comment: On my computer office 2010 But on the other one is office 2007